# For html canvas, how to create two contexts then composite the two?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Using html canvas, I want to have two context variables, ctx1 and ctx2, then composite the two into the final context.

Currently I assume it is possible using two canvas elements. But I don't know any exact technique or if there exists a simpler technique. Please help me to achieve my objective.

As complement, my true objective is not to have 2 contexts, but to composite 2 image data I have drawn separately.

```
let ctx1;
let ctx2;
let canvas1 = document.getElementById('canvas1');
if (canvas.getContext) {
  ctx1 = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx1.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
}
let canvas2 = document.getElementById('canvas2');
if (canvas.getContext) {
  ctx2 = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx2.fillRect(50,50,100,100);
}

// Here I want to composite ctx1 and ctx2.
```

Comment: To clarify; you want to take the contents of one canvas and add them to the other? Have you tried getting the innerHTML of the canvas?

Comment: (You may want to give an example of the desired results).

Comment: @Paul, thank you very much. I 'll edit it to include the desired result.

Comment: You can use a canvas as an image source for another canvas. So, ctx1.drawImage(canvas2,0,0) will combine the two canvas contents onto canvas1.You can position the drawing using the 2nd & 3rd params of .drawImage